# duvida com download de arquivos

Tags: c#, html, download, stream-de-arquivos

tenho um pasta na nuvem, e quero gerar um list na paginal html, com todos esses arquivo, para que quando o usuario clicar, abrir o downlaod do arquivo, estou tentando da seguinte forma(esse codigo é só de teste):

```
<a href="http://zulex.com.br/upload/CLIDET.DBF" download>                                                   
    <img border="0" src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>
```

no chrome funciona, abre a janela para download, porem no firefox e no IE, o browser tentar abrir arquivo, ao inves de abrir a tela de download, como posso melhorar esse codigo?

Comment: Nem todos navegadores suportam mesmo, isso pode ser [visto aqui](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download). Na aba "*known issues*" diz que o Firefox suporta somente [same-origin](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=874009).

Comment: Isso dai é um comportamento do navegador de tentar executar em vez de fazer o download daquilo que ele ja conhece como abre, tome como exemplo o .pdf que é aberto no navegador em vez de ser feito o download para sua máquina muitas vezes. Não sei se pode te ajudar, mas tem uma biblioteca de boa para fazer "forçar" o download a FileSaver.js ve se te ajuda https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Answer (score -1):

```
 var files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\path", "*.*",
    SearchOption.AllDirectories)

List<string> imageFiles = new List<string>();
  foreach (string filename in files)
 {
  if (Regex.IsMatch(filename, @".jpg|.png|.gif$"))
    imageFiles.Add(filename);
 }
```

EM asp MVC ou C#,net 
em asp
VEJA O LINK ve c te ajuda!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047228/listing-folders-in-a-directory-using-asp-net-and-c-sharp